# Two linked jQuery Sliders adding up to 100%

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I'm trying to link two jQuery UI sliders so they'll add up to 100%. I've found the perfect solution for three sliders here on SO, but for some reason I am unable to get the math to add up correctly when modifying this jsFiddle example to strip out the third slider: http://jsfiddle.net/gWbMp/3/

Can anyone help me out in forking this to simply include two sliders instead of three?

Here's the (close) javascript I've ended up with but it's not quite right:

```
var min = 0;
var max = 100;
$("input").change(function(){
 console.log("a");
     var index = $(this).attr('class').substring(0,1);
    $("#slider_"+ index).slider('value', this.value);
    refreshSliders( index - 0 );
});
$('.selector').slider({
    animate : true
}, {
    min : min
}, {
    max : max
}, {
    change : function(event, ui) {
        totalvalue = $("#slider_1").slider("value") + $("#slider_2").slider("value");
        $('.1percent').val($("#slider_1").slider("value"));
        $('.2percent').val($("#slider_2").slider("value"));

    }
}, {
    slide : function(event, ui) {
        $('.1percent').val($("#slider_1").slider("value"));
        $('.2percent').val($("#slider_2").slider("value"));

    }
});

$("#slider_1").slider('value', 10);
$("#slider_2").slider('value', 90);

$('.1percent').val($("#slider_1").slider("value"));
$('.2percent').val($("#slider_2").slider("value"));

function refreshSliders(slidermainin) {
    var value1 = $("#slider_1").slider("option", "value");
    var value2 = $("#slider_2").slider("option", "value");
    var valuechange = (value1 + value2) - 100;
    var valuemain = 0, valueother1 = 0;

    switch(slidermainin) {
        case 1:
            slidermain = "#slider_1";
            sliderother1 = "#slider_2";
            valuemain = value1;
            valueother1 = value2;
            break;
        case 2:
            slidermain = "#slider_2";
            sliderother1 = "#slider_1";
            valuemain = value2;
            valueother1 = value1;
            break;
    }

    if (valueother1 === 0) {
        if (valueother1 === 0) {
            if (valuechange <= 0) {
                $(sliderother1).slider('value', valueother1 - (valuechange / 2));
            }
        } else {
            if (valuechange <= 0) {
                $(sliderother1).slider('value', valueother1 - (valuechange / 2));
            } else {
                $(sliderother1).slider('value', valueother1 - valuechange);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $(sliderother1).slider('value', valueother1 - (valuechange / 2));
    }
}

var bindSliders = function(selector, value) {
    $(selector).bind("slidechange slide", function(event, ui) {
        event.originalEvent && (event.originalEvent.type == 'mousemove' || event.originalEvent.type == 'mouseup' || event.originalEvent.type == 'keydown') && refreshSliders(value);
    });
};

bindSliders("#slider_1", 1);
bindSliders("#slider_2", 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done much shorter for two sliders

You can rewrite refreshSliders function to calculate second value on the basis of max value
And call it directly on slider "change" and "slide" (or even just second one)

```
function refreshSliders(thisSlider, ui){    
var thisNum = $(thisSlider).attr("id").replace("slider_", "");
var otherNum = (thisNum==1)?2:1;  
$('.'+thisNum+'percent').val(ui.value);
if ($("#slider_"+otherNum).slider("value")!=max-ui.value){             
      $("#slider_"+otherNum).slider("value", max-ui.value);
      $('.'+otherNum+'percent').val(max-ui.value); 
 }    
}
```

have a look at this jsfiddle, i forked it from original one and adjusted a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/fBxCm/1/

Comment: Hello Paulitto, nice solution. I have a similar question but for three sliders. Could you please help me. The question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962396/jquery-ui-multiple-linked-range-sliders-with-sum-of-1